# The type or namespace name 'MovieTexture' could not be found.Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#

During this cause of executing my application, i'm encountering the

> error(CS0246)
>    error

when i'm trying to build my game on unity using WebGL.Here's the code :

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

using UnityEngine.UI;



[RequireComponent (typeof(AudioSource))]

public class videoplayer : MonoBehaviour {

private MovieTexture movie;

private AudioSource audio;


    void Start () {

        GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = movie as MovieTexture;
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        audio.clip = movie.audioClip;
        movie.Play ();
        audio.Play();


    }


    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: have you put your cursor on `MovieTexture` and hit `ctrl` `.` and then check to see if there is a using statement?

Comment: i did this and the debug showed this : " Field 'videoplayer.movie' is never assigned to,and will always have its default  value null "

Comment: *i did this and the debug showed 2*.. what do you mean?  you mean the Intellisense? which Using statements did you see?

Comment: ohh,sorry.i see only Texture.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got the problem. Basically, the `movie` is declared and not assigned any value.That is why it is null.
I think you have missed the name of the object whose texture property is used here

`GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = movie as MovieTexture;`.

It should be like:

`GetComponent<RawImage>()."THE NAME".texture = movie as MovieTexture;`